Movie with several people finding crashed small plane in forest that is loaded with gold
I saw a movie on afternoon TV between 2001 and 2004. I thought it might be called Fool's Gold, but a couple years ago I checked every movie on IMDB with that title and none of them were it. Several people hiking in the forest come across a crashed small plane. They find it is loaded with gold bars. They agree to leave it and come back for the gold with something to carry it.
The bad guys who already know about the plane and its contents come looking for it. They cross paths with the group of people. They would have continued on and left the people alone, but one of the people violated their agreement and was carrying gold bars. The bad guys hear two gold bars clank together. They make the people take them to the plane crash. Then they make them carry the gold out of the forest. They hide the gold in the gas tank of a motor home.
Along the way the bad guys and the other people have been killing each other. At the end there is the main bad guy and a woman left. The bad guy guy is strangling the woman and a cop pointing a gun at him tells him to stop. He says "just a minute" and finishes strangling the woman. Then the cop finally shoots him. So everyone who knows about the gold is dead and the motor home loaded with gold is being towed to the junk yard.

Nice Q. See my top-voted answer in the link above.

Thanks. I'm sure The Killing Grounds is the movie I've been looking for. I'm not sure why I thought the title might be Fool's Gold although I think that would be an appropriate title for it.

FWIW, according to IMDb it's called something like 'Gold Chase' in Hungarian.

Sounds similar to A Simple Plan (1998) but pretty sure the plane is full of money not gold. It stars Bill Paxton and Billy Bob Thornton.  (How much gold can you carry in a light aircraft - maybe that's why it crashed)

@DForck42 This is 'The Killing Grounds'. The OP has described the plot to a T, right down to the ending.

As mentioned in the comments. The answer to this question is the Killing Grounds (1998).
